# Rsyslog dropping large messages

Tags: django, docker, rsyslog

I am using rsyslog to forward logs from a docker container to splunk. The docker container runs django which is configured to write all of our application logs to syslog. After a couple of weirdities involving timestamps, everything works great ... except that large messages (approx 2K or above) are dropped (not even truncated). I tried to set the $MaxMessageSize to 64k in rsyslog.conf but it had no effect. If django could be configured to write logs to a TCP socket, or the $MaxMessageSize actually worked, I would be good to go. Any help is appreciated.

rsyslogd  8.2001.0
Python 3.8.5
Django 3.1.2
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Docker? Can you use the logging drivers built into Docker? Will Django support standard output logging?

I think you will simplify your setup in a big way if you can use Docker's well tested logging drivers.

Another option is a interesting open source project called Appscope https://github.com/criblio/appscope. It supports all things container from the kernel level so gives you metrics and logging as well.